# PostgreSQL: sequential table scan on Hstore column despite having a GiN index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, hstore

I have a table with a `hstore` column and roughly **22 mio records** (the ways table from a partial osm-database).

Despite having a **GIN** index on the hstore column, queries for a specific tag result in a **sequential table scan** that takes > 60 sec to return a single column.

What i have been doing so far.

1. I created the GIN index using pgAdminIII.
2. Executing `vacuum analayze`
3. Executing a query of the kind: `select id from table where tags->'name'='foo'`
4. Deleting index and starting from 1. again ...
5. [Edit] As suggested by the user a_horse_with_no_name I updated the table statistics by executing `analyze` on the table. But that had no effect.

[image]

You can see the query plan [**here**](http://explain.depesz.com/s/r2yP). For some reason the `explain analyze` takes only ~20 sec to complete.

**How can I properly index a hstore column on a large table like this, to reduce query execution cost significantly?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I executed analyze ways, but there are still no improvements in query execution speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions:

If you always query that key value for equality you can use an a B-Tree index on the expression (`tags -> 'name')

```
create index idx_name on ways ( (tags -> 'name') );
```

A quick test has shown that Postgres does use the index to find if a key value is present in the hstore column, but apparently not for finding the associated value.

So you could try to add a condition to test for that key value as well:

```
select id
from ways
where tags ? 'name' 
  and tags -> 'name' = 'Wiehbergpark';
```

If all rows contain that key, it might not help though.

Comment: That finally reduced query cost to 10 ms! Great! Thank you.

Comment: @achingfingers: which of the two alternatives did you use?

Comment: As i already tried the second one before, i created the btree index on the 'name' tag.